# Copy value with some condition

Tags: vba, excel

I have number 1 to 10 in *Column A* and `name` in *Column B*. What I am trying to accomplish is to check the `name` in cell B2, if empty then it will copy the number from cell A2 to cell H2. But if cell B2 already contains a name then it will copy the number from cell A3 to cell H2 and so on.

**Here is my code:**

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
If IsEmpty(Range("B2")) Then
    Range("A2").Copy destination:=Range("H2")
Else
    Worksheets("sheet6").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1).Copy _
        destination:=Range("H2")
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Scenario: B2 has a name and B3 does not have a name.  Using the above logic: The contents in H2 would be overwritten when processing B3.

Comment: yes the value in H2 will change every time  i put another name in column B

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
With Sheets("SheetName")
    .Range("B:B").Find(vbNullString, [B1]).Offset(0, -1).Copy _
        Destination:=.Range("H2")
End With
```

This finds the first blank cell after `B1` and then copies its corresponding value in A to H2.

**Edit1:** If `H2` is in a different workbook

```
Dim otherWB As Workbook ' always declare variable
Set otherWB = Workbooks("WorkbookName.xlsx") ' or whatever name you got

With Sheets("SheetName")
    .Range("B:B").Find(vbNullString, [B1]).Offset(0, -1).Copy _
        Destination:=otherWB.Sheets("OtherSheetName").Range("H2")
End With
```

Comment: thanks, your code work perfectly, but is it possible if cell H2 is placed in another workbooks? thanks

Comment: @uniks Sure. Just reference it to that workbook. See my edit.

Comment: I've tried but nothing happened,  here is my code  
`Private Sub CopyNota_Click()

On Error GoTo errorhandler:
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim strpath As String

strpath = "E:\b\"

Filename = Dir(strpath & "b.xlsx")

    With Sheets("Sheet5")
        .Range("B:B").Find(vbNullString, [B2]).Offset(0, -1).Copy _
        destination:=.Workbooks("b.xlsx").Worksheets("sheet3").Range("A2")
    End With

errorhandler:
If Err.Number = "52" Then
    MsgBox "Open The Workbooks First!!!"
    Exit Sub
End If

End Sub`